# Facebook shares uses wrong image and text after sharing

Tags: php, facebook

I am using facebook share.

So to customize the sharing image and text i use the following code

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s= 100&amp;p[title]=Mulankidz&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url;?>&amp;p[images][0]=http://www.mulankidz.com/images/vie.gif&amp;p[summary]=Welcome to MuLan Educational Games, a unique portal that specializes in online educational games for kids." class="facebook" title="Facebook" target="_blank"></a>
```

when i try to share the page it showing the content and image what i used in the above code..

[image]

But after pressing share button and it's shared on my timeline.. which is showing the following content..

[image]

Here is my website link where i am using the above code to share when click on facebook icon.
[website page link here](http://www.mulankidz.com/videos/videos.php)

I don't have any idea..why it is showing the content and images differently after sharing..

Any help.. and suggestions acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url to image" />
```

On your page for FB to read the image while posting.

Read here how to do it

http://moz.com/blog/meta-data-templates-123

UPDATE

I tried the facebook debug tool for your URL 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mulankidz.com%2Fvideos%2Fvideos.php

This gives me following -

```
og:image should be larger   
Provided og:image is not big enough. 
Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. 
Image http://www.mulankidz.com/videos/../images/star.gif
will be used instead.
```

You need to provide an image at least 200x200 px

Comment: I added the meta tag to my code and it's not working..i use as follows    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mulankidz.com/images/vie.gif" />

Comment: no the image path should be full yourdomain.com/path-to-image

Comment: I see u gave full path

Comment: ok I know why the Debugger says as og:image should be larger Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://www.mulankidz.com/videos/../images/star.gif' will be used instead.  so u need to provide the image with that specification on the meta tag before posting to FB. This should fix it

Comment: any idea why it's behaving so wearied.. i am trying to rectify this and spend whole day on this..

Comment: the image issue is fixed.. but text is not displaying why?

Comment: Better to specify those on the org tags see the link I sent you

Comment: Cool.. you should follow the new FB API like Graph and Open Graph they make life simple :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47503/discussion-between-abhik-chakraborty-and-phpcoder)

Answer (score 0):

You may have changed the image after creating the application. Try recreating the application from developer.facebook.com. Hopefully it will take effect.